# name 'AddressLocator' is not defined, Python created Address Locator

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

When I run this tool, I get the error 'name 'locator_AddressLocator_n_' is not defined'.

My guess is that this is an issue with the path where the locator is trying to save to?  So, I am assuming I have not set the workspace or the scratch workspace?  These are just guesses though.

I will need to save each of the geocoding outputs, so should I just have the code create a new GDB and push the outputs to that location?  How could this be accomplished?

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = 1
```

Here is the geocoder code:

```
arcpy.CreateAddressLocator_geocoding("General - Single Field", inputFC+"'Primary Table'", "'Feature ID' '' VISIBLE NONE;*KeyField GeoLabel VISIBLE NONE;'Additional Field' '' VISIBLE NONE;'Altname JoinID' '' VISIBLE NONE", locator_AddressLocator_n_, "")
```

UPDATE:

Created a GDB from paramter and set the workspace to that location, but I am still getting the same error when running the script.  name 'AddressLocator' is not defined

```
inputGDBname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
inputGDBloc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

#Create GDB for address locators
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(inputGDBloc, inputGDBname)

env.workspace = inputGDBloc+"/"+inputGDBname
```

**UPDATE**

New Error on the last line...

RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

I have included all of my code this time, just so everything is visible to see what could be throwing the error.

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = 1

#Create GDB for address locators
inputGDBname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputGDBloc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(inputGDBloc, inputGDBname)
env.workspace = os.path.join(inputGDBloc, inputGDBname)

#Get FC and Fields
inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
inputField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
inputFieldLabel = "GeoLabel"
inputFieldName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

#Add the GeoLabel field to the Selected Feature Class
arcpy.AddField_management(inputFC, inputFieldLabel, "TEXT")

#Calculate the field values for the selected field and populate it with the inputFieldLabel + InputField
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inputFC)
for row in rows:
    idt = row.getValue(inputField)
    exp = inputFieldName + ': ' + idt
    row.setValue('GeoLabel', exp)
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row, rows

Reference_Data = inputFC + ' Primary Table'
RefData = Reference_Data

arcpy.CreateAddressLocator_geocoding("General - Single Field", RefData, "'Feature ID' <None> VISIBLE NONE;*KeyField GeoLabel VISIBLE NONE;'Additional Field' <None> VISIBLE NONE;'Altname JoinID' <None> VISIBLE NONE", "Address_Loc_n_", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting up the enviroment

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "geodatabase file (inculding path)"
env.overwriteOutput = 1
#Here is the geocoder code:

arcpy.CreateAddressLocator_geocoding("General - Single Field", inputFC+"'Primary Table'", "'Feature ID' '' VISIBLE NONE;*KeyField GeoLabel VISIBLE NONE;'Additional Field' '' VISIBLE NONE;'Altname JoinID' '' VISIBLE NONE", locator_AddressLocator_n_, "")
```

edit:
try using the join:

```
env.workspace = os.path.join(inputGDBloc,inputGDBname)
```